# Nvidia Geforce Experience is asking for access to a protected item: password for CryptoAPI Private Key, what does that mean?

Tags: windows-10, security, nvidia-graphics-card, private-key

Recently when I start Nvidia Geforce Experience, my OS (windows 10 64bit)  pops up a dialog to warn me that this program wants to access my private keys.

I've had just a little previous experience with this dialog: If I want to export a private email signing key, the OS would warn me like that.

But why does Geforce Experience want to access the private key store?

---

Edit:

OK, I found a cert under Certificates - Local Computer -> Personal -> Certificates, there's a self-signed cert issued to/by "NVIDIA GameStream Server", which is an untrustred CA Root cert (but it's installed under "Personal certificates") with **all** purposes enabled (such as code-signing, Microsoft Trust List Signing, Windows Update...)

If you have Geforce Experience installed, may you please check whether you also have this cert on your computer? If not then I probably should change all my bank password from a new device...

Comment: I've got the exact same key. It's valid for 20 years and it's weird because other PCs do not have this issue.

Comment: Could you post the thumbprint of the certificate? It can be found in Properties > Details.

Comment: Has someone an explanation for this weird certificate? I noticed it today too in my MMC Snap-In. I 100% sure, that it was not there some months back.